# No value displayed from custom resource layout input

Tags: java, android

I'm working on a todo application and I'm using an Alertdialog as a popup for all relevant task information. Everything is working as expected, my only issue is that after the matercardview has been added, the value I entered in the EditText on the custom resource layout does not show. Neither if I use Toast. What could cause this to happen.

The custom resource file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/taskName"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:padding="8dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtTaskName"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/taskName"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="45dp"
            android:autofillHints="@string/taskName"
            android:inputType="text"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/addtask"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
            android:focusable="true" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/taskDesc"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:padding="8dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtDesc"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/task_desc"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:autofillHints="@string/task_desc"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:layout_marginStart="45dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/Date"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:padding="8dp">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:text="@string/task_date"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:onClick="onDateCreate"
            android:layout_marginStart="45dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/Remind"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:padding="8dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/remind"
            android:onClick="onTimeCreate"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="45dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

My MaterialCardView

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    app:cardElevation="5dp">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
            android:text="@string/daily"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/cardView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtTime"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/daily"
            android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="44dp"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cardView"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
            app:cardCornerRadius="50dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

My Code

```
    public void ShowTaskDialog(Context c){
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(c);
        View alertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.add_daily, null);

        alert.setView(alertView);
        alert.setPositiveButton("Post", (dialog, which) -> {
            LinearLayout taskView = findViewById(R.id.taskArea);
            View addItemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.add_daily, null);
            View task_View = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_list, null);

            EditText textView = (EditText) addItemView.findViewById(R.id.txtTaskName);
            String taskName = textView.getText().toString();

            TextView txtName = task_View.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
            txtName.setText(taskName);
            taskView.addView(task_View);
        });
        alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //Close Alert
            }
        });
        alertDialog = alert.show();
        alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
        alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.WHITE));
    }
```

Comment: Get rid of the `View addItemView = ...` in the dialog callback. That's creating a completely separate instance of the dialog layout. The `View`s you want are in `View alertView`.

Comment: @MikeM. if I remove it I get this ```Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference```

Comment: You still need to call `findViewById()` to get your `View`s. You just need to call it on `alertView` instead.

Comment: @MikeM. Can you elaborate what you mean with call it on ```AlertView```

Comment: `EditText textView = (EditText) alertView.findViewById(R.id.txtTaskName);`.

Comment: @MikeM. You're a legend, can you post that so I can mark as answer please

Comment: you need to call `alertView .findViewById(R.id.txtTaskName);` like this hope helpful for you

Comment: Cool. Glad you got it working. I'm good, however. Please feel free to post an answer yourself, if you like, or to wait for someone else to post, or to mark it as a duplicate. Thank you, though. I appreciate the offer. Cheers!

Comment: @MikeM. Do you know how I can add spacing between the items after I added them

Comment: Do you mean between the `task_View`s? If you change the inflation as follows, then the `layout_margin*` attributes on the `<MaterialCardView>` will work, and you could use top/bottom margins to adjust that: `View task_View = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_list, taskView, false);`.

Comment: @MikeM. Got it appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `findViewById()` on alertView to get your Views.

```
alertView .findViewById(R.id.txtTaskName);
```

Comment: Please explain your answer!